# XML Serialization of Binary Literals

Tags: c#, binary, xml-serialization, literals

I have a class to the effect of:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public ushort Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The property `Bar` stores the state of 16 Boolean "flags" that are used as configuration toggles, similar to DIP switches.

The class `Foo` itself is a data model that it serialized to human readable xml for configuration.

For intuition's sake, I would like that `Bar` serializes to, and desterilizes from a binary literal, such as:

```xml
<Foo>
  <Bar>0b_1000_1010_1000_1110</Bar>
</Foo>
```

How might this be achieved? Many Thanks.

Comment: I believe you'll have to implement `IXmlSerializable` interface for your class and implement all that manually

Comment: @Evk Thanks, I was worried that might be the case :( Perhaps I'll just implement an array of bools instead and handle the conversions in the backend.

Comment: Xml serializer in .NET is very inflexible and I'd even say it's design is quite outdated. If you could use json for your config instead...

Comment: XML will not allow a binary number (ushort) so you have to convert to a string.  I would use a csv string like following :             ushort[] data = null;
            string.Join(",", data.Select(x => x.ToString("X4")));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();